# Build Firefox Fennec with Flash Player embedded

Tags: android, flash, firefox, compiler-construction, makefile

I'm building Firefox Fennec from source and I would like to embed adobe flash player (libflashplayer.so), in a way that users could start using flash as soon as they open the browser.

I'm sorry for not having a starting point, but the build instructions provided by Mozilla don't cover this topic.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you legally allowed to redistribute the flash player library?

Comment: Etan: This is for test purposes only and I don't plan to commercialize this app, based on this,  I'm not worried about the legal ramifications, thanks for pointing that anyway.